# Max activities in a feed is 3600, where can I configure a higher number?

Tags: getstream-io

The max activities in a feed is defaulted at 3600 according to the api docs.  I am unable to find in the UI where to set this to something else.  Also, what happens when the max is reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `3600` limit is the maximum amount of activities you can read for a single feed via APIs. This is a hard limit and can't be increased.

The way the limit is enforced is very simple: when you read a feed, you always get results from the latest 3600 activities.

Comment: Thanks Tommaso, makes total sense now!  I doubt users would care about activities that are older than 3600 anyways.

Comment: What can we do in case we need way more than 3600 activities? Imagine an enterprise solution where 1000s of users can put a verb onto an object? Imagine something like Facebook reactions.

Comment: @ManuelReil for the case of 1000 users reacting to a single item, you likely would want to use an [aggregated feed](https://getstream.io/docs/?language=js#aggregated-feeds). Seeing each like is probably not meaningful for your users, but each object which is liked would be valuable. I hope that helps.